# why pyqt5 gui lags when encrypting files with pyAesCrypt

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, encryption, pyqt5

I have made a gui which will encrypt and decrypt my files.For that i am using pyAesCrypt module.
here is my code

```
import pyAesCrypt
from PyQt5 import QtCore
bufferSize = 64 * 1024
password = "net1234"
def encrypt(self):
   pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(input_file_path , output_file_name_with_path+".aes", password, bufferSize)
thread=QtCore.QThread(self)
thread.started.connect(self.encrypt)
thread.start()
```

but instead of QThread if i use normal Thread then GUI does not lag.Here i have written only the function to encrypt not decrypt.Any help will be appreciated.Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code you are only indicating that when the thread starts to invoke "encrypt" but you are executing in the thread that QThread handles. The solution is that "encrypt" is a method of a QObject that lives in the secondary thread and that the method is invoked through a signal or a similar method.

```
import functools

import pyAesCrypt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


bufferSize = 64 * 1024
password = "net1234"


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def encrypt(self, input_file_path, output_file_name_with_path):
        try:
            pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(
                input_file_path,
                output_file_name_with_path + ".aes",
                password,
                bufferSize,
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)

        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(thread)
        thread.start()

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start)

    def start(self):
        input_file_path = ""
        output_file_name_with_path = ""
        wrapper = functools.partial(
            self.worker.encrypt, input_file_path, output_file_name_with_path
        )
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

w = Widget()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks!!your code works fine.but can u make me understand in a simpler way(i am not talking about codes) that is the line`With your code you are only indicating that when the thread starts to invoke "encrypt" but you are executing in the thread that QThread handles. The solution is that "encrypt" is a method of a QObject that lives in the secondary thread and that the method is invoked through a signal or a similar method.`

Comment: @Rajkumar That is the simple way to explain, I am unable to make it simpler unfortunately.

Comment: Ok Thank u a lot.